# Выборка MySQL. Группировка по значениям и подсчет их количества?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL

[image: таблица]

в statusp могут быть значения только 0,1,2,3
на данном примере должны получить следующий результат выборки

0 значений 1шт,
1        - 3 шт,
2        - 1 шт,
3        -3 шт

Каким образом сделать выборку чтобы происходила группировка по значениям и подсчитать их количество для каждой группировки ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
SELECT `statusp`, COUNT(*) as `statusp_count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `statusp`
```

Comment: @Akina хорошо. исправил.